# BootStrap MultiSelect ToolTip Remove Comma

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect

Is there a way to remove the comma from bootstrap's multiselect tooltip?

To remove the tooltip, we just need to add `, buttonTitle: function() {}`

But I couldn't find any examples on how to edit the tooltip.

Here's the multiselect tooltip code:

```
          $(function ()
                {
                    $("#@(Model.Name)").multiselect({
                        includeSelectAllOption: true
                        //, selectAllValue: "[All]"
                        , selectAllText: "(Select All)"
                        , enableFiltering: true
                        , enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true
                        , onDropdownShown: function (event) {
                            this.$select.parent().find("button.multiselect-clear-filter").click();
                            this.$select.parent().find("input[type='text'].multiselect-search").focus();    
                        }
                        , nonSelectedText: "  "
                        , onInitialized: function () {
                            $("#@(Model.Name)InitialLoading").hide();
                            $(".@(Model.ItemName)").hide();
                        }
                        , onChange: function () {
                            ListChangeHandler($("select[id=@Model.Name]"));
                            CheckSelection($("select[id=@Model.Name]"),"@(Model.ItemName)");
                        }
                        , onSelectAll: function () {
                            ListChangeHandler($("select[id=@Model.Name]"));
                            $(".@(Model.ItemName)").hide();
                        }
                        , onDeselectAll: function () {
                            ClearWholeList($("select[id=@Model.Name]"));
                            ListChangeHandler($("select[id=@Model.Name]"));
                            $(".@(Model.ItemName)").show();
                        }
                        , buttonTitle: function() {} //tooltip title
                        @*@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ChangeHandler) ? ", onChange: " + Model.ChangeHandler + ", onSelectAll: " + Model.ChangeHandler + ", onDeselectAll: " + Model.ChangeHandler : "")*@
                    });


                    LoadListBox("@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CascadedFromName) ? Model.Name : "")");

                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, here's the buttonTitle function:

```
,buttonTitle: function(options, select) {
    var labels = [];
    options.each(function () {
        labels.push($(this).text());
    });
    return labels.join('');
}
```